# How to display time with Am or PM in visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I need to create a field with time only. So, I had created a `Visualforce Page` and a custom controller that will work with only Html 5.0.

Once the user try to create any account I am roting my `Visulaforce Page` with capturing current time of the user working perfectly fine. After user saves the record I update the time in a custom text field and display in normal standard page. Everything works fine.

But after user saves the record it displays like:

> Time  19:34:00.000Z

But I need

> 7:38 AM/PM.

My Apex class

```
public class MyTimeController {

   public Account acc{get;set;}
   public String var{get;set;}
   public Boolean edit{get;set;}
    public MyTimeController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    var=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id'); 
     if(var!=null){

     acc=[Select Id,Name,Time__c from Account where Id=:var];
     edit=true;
     }
     else{
     edit=false;
     acc=new Account();
     }    

    }


    public PageReference save() {
       acc.Time__c=String.ValueOf(myTime);
       if(!edit){
       insert acc;
       }
       else{
       update acc;
       }
       PageReference redirectPage =  new PageReference('/'+acc.id);
       redirectPage.setRedirect(true);
       return redirectPage;
       return null;
    }


    public Time myTime { 
        get {
            if (myTime == null) {
                myTime =  DateTime.now().Time();

            }
            return myTime;
        } 
        set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of

```
acc.Time__c=String.ValueOf(myTime);
```

Use:

```
Datetime myDateTime = Datetime.newInstance(Date.today(), myTime);
acc.Time__c = myDateTime.format('h:mm a');
```